# Where in the project tree to save gatsby-config.js

Tags: gatsby

Hi I'm following the tutorial in part 2:

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-two/

and am getting stuck with:

> Next create a file at the base of your site named gatsby-config.js.
>   This is where you add plugins to a site along with other site
>   configuration.

Where is the base of my site?  The root folder, the `public` folder, the `src` folder, or `src/pages`?

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer looking at the examples on github.  Should be  created under src/

Answer (score 4):

The "base of your site" is the same thing as the "root of your site". Good luck with the tutorials!

Comment: Thanks. Something still not going right. Re-running gatsby develop doesn't seem to insert a <style> element in the head as in [https://www.gatsbyjs.org/static/2c34a22832b1dd0828ac87fde925622a-0c745.png[